# Inconsistent reasons to delete an answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, link-only-answers

I was wondering why the reasons to flag an answer are different than the reasons to delete it (in the review area for example).

Let's take an example. In the review area, there's the "link-only answer" reason, but that's not present in the flag answer section. So what I did was to enter "another reason (needs moderator attention). Of course that got declined, because it doesn't really need mod attention. So in this case, what was I supposed to do?

I'm proposing a feature request to add the "link-only answer" reason to the flag popup (as well as others if needed), but also adding the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag, cause I want to know if it's just me that's bothered by this.

Comment: Link only answers are Not an Answer. Flag as Not an Answer for link only answers. When you flag as other for mod attention, it goes to an actual mod, so they decline it for wasting their time. When you flag as Not an Answer it goes to the Low Quality Review Queue for normal users to review.

Comment: @cVplZ is this documented anywhere, or is it just a matter of experience using the site?

Comment: Yes it is.. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer